# Installing Apache 2.4 and PHP 7 on Windows 10

Tags: php, apache, windows-10

I'm trying to install Apache 2.4.38 and PHP 7.3.1 on my Windows 10 machine, but I'm getting the following error:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 185 of C:/Anton/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/php7apache2_4.dll into server: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
```

I'm using the following versions of Apache and PHP:

- httpd-2.4.38-win32-VC15.zip
- php-7.3.1-Win32-VC15-x86.zip

Things I've already checked:

- Both Apache and PHP are compiled with the same version of C++ Redistributable Visual Studio
- I'm using the Thread Safe version of PHP
- The file php7apache2_4.dll is in the main PHP folder and I've copied it to the folder Apache24/modules

I've added the following lines to the httpd.conf file line

- LoadModule php7_module modules/php7apache2_4.dll
- AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
- PHPIniDir "C:/Anton/PHP7"

I've also tried using the x64 variant, but with the same result. What am I missing / doing wrong?

Comment: `Syntax error on line 185` what is on line 185?

Comment: That's the line "LoadModule php7_module modules/php7apache2_4.dll" (without the quotes)

Comment: I see that "Kan opgegeven module niet vinden" means "Can not find specified module" so, is the path correct?

Comment: The folder "C:\Anton\Apache24\modules" exists and I've copied the file "php7apache2_4.dll" to this folder.

Comment: Have your tried XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)? It makes things very easy.

Comment: I've used XAMPP for temporary servers, and yes it is easy, but for this server I prefer the original versions of Apache and PHP. It shouldn't be so hard...

Answer (score 1):

The following change worked. Changing the line:

> LoadModule php7_module modules/php7apache2_4.dll

to

> LoadModule php7_module C:/Anton/PHP7/php7apache2_4.dll